# How to speed up bilinear interpolation of image?

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, interpolation, image-rotation

I'm trying to rotate image with interpolation, but it's too slow for real time for big images.

the code something like:

```
for(int y=0;y<dst_h;++y)
{
    for(int x=0;x<dst_w;++x)
    {
        //do inverse transform
        fPoint pt(Transform(Point(x, y)));

        //in coor of src
        int x1= (int)floor(pt.x);
        int y1= (int)floor(pt.y);
        int x2= x1+1;
        int y2= y1+1;


        if((x1>=0&&x1<src_w&&y1>=0&&y1<src_h)&&(x2>=0&&x2<src_w&&y2>=0&&y2<src_h))
        {
                Mask[y][x]= 1; //show pixel

                float dx1= pt.x-x1;
                float dx2= 1-dx1;
                float dy1= pt.y-y1;
                float dy2= 1-dy1;

                //bilinear
                pd[x].blue= (dy2*(ps[y1*src_w+x1].blue*dx2+ps[y1*src_w+x2].blue*dx1)+
                        dy1*(ps[y2*src_w+x1].blue*dx2+ps[y2*src_w+x2].blue*dx1));
                pd[x].green= (dy2*(ps[y1*src_w+x1].green*dx2+ps[y1*src_w+x2].green*dx1)+
                        dy1*(ps[y2*src_w+x1].green*dx2+ps[y2*src_w+x2].green*dx1));
                pd[x].red= (dy2*(ps[y1*src_w+x1].red*dx2+ps[y1*src_w+x2].red*dx1)+
                        dy1*(ps[y2*src_w+x1].red*dx2+ps[y2*src_w+x2].red*dx1));

                //nearest neighbour
                //pd[x]= ps[((int)pt.y)*src_w+(int)pt.x];
        }
        else
                Mask[y][x]= 0; //transparent pixel
    }
    pd+= dst_w;
}
```

How I can speed up this code, I try to parallelize this code but it seems there is no speed up because of memory access pattern (?).

Comment: Seems to be more appropriate for codereview.se

Comment: You can also use the Intel IPP library which has an optimized function for bilinear interpolation.  This lib optimizes for both SIMD instructions (faster single thread performance) and for multicore usage, for some cases.  The only downside is that this SDK is payware.  If that doesn't work for your needs, then you should try OpenMP.

Answer (score 5):

The key is to do most of your computations as ints.  The only thing that is necessary to do as a float is the weighting.  See [here](http://fastcpp.blogspot.com/2011/06/bilinear-pixel-interpolation-using-sse.html) for a good resource.

From that same resource:

```
int px = (int)x; // floor of x
int py = (int)y; // floor of y
const int stride = img->width;
const Pixel* p0 = img->data + px + py * stride; // pointer to first pixel

// load the four neighboring pixels
const Pixel& p1 = p0[0 + 0 * stride];
const Pixel& p2 = p0[1 + 0 * stride];
const Pixel& p3 = p0[0 + 1 * stride];
const Pixel& p4 = p0[1 + 1 * stride];

// Calculate the weights for each pixel
float fx = x - px;
float fy = y - py;
float fx1 = 1.0f - fx;
float fy1 = 1.0f - fy;

int w1 = fx1 * fy1 * 256.0f;
int w2 = fx  * fy1 * 256.0f;
int w3 = fx1 * fy  * 256.0f;
int w4 = fx  * fy  * 256.0f;

// Calculate the weighted sum of pixels (for each color channel)
int outr = p1.r * w1 + p2.r * w2 + p3.r * w3 + p4.r * w4;
int outg = p1.g * w1 + p2.g * w2 + p3.g * w3 + p4.g * w4;
int outb = p1.b * w1 + p2.b * w2 + p3.b * w3 + p4.b * w4;
int outa = p1.a * w1 + p2.a * w2 + p3.a * w3 + p4.a * w4;
```

Answer (score 1):

**wow you are doing a lot inside most inner loop like**:

1.float to int conversions

- can do all on floats ...
- they are these days pretty fast
- the conversion is what is killing you
- also you are mixing float and ints together (if i see it right) which is the same ...

2.transform(x,y)

- any unnecessary call makes heap trashing and slow things down
- instead add 2 variables xx,yy and interpolate them insde your for loops

3.if ....

- why to heck are you adding if ?
- limit the for ranges before loop and not inside ...
- the background can be filled with other fors  before or later